# Register a callback function in a service that gets called when the service trigger the callback in AngularJs with TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

How can I register/subscribe to a `callback method` from an `AngularJs` `controller` to an `AngularJs` `service`?

I want to set a `$scope.property` value when my '**loader**' running in my service has reached 100%.

I want to return a `Boolean`, of `true` to my `controller` from my `service`.

**I had something like the following in mind:**
Create a `method` in my `controller` that gets registered in my `service`, that gets called when my loader has reached 100% in my `service`. I am just not sure whether I am on the right track, and how to fill in the missing pieces.

**Controller:**

```
this._scope.loaderHasLoaded = this._progressBarService.loaderHasCompleted.push(function done(): boolean{})
```

**Service:**

```
public loadingComplete():boolean{  
   if (this.isLoaderLoaded === true)   {  
      return true
   }   else   {  
      return false;
   }
}

// some missing functionality

public loaderHasCompleted =[];
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's the wrong way to go. Service should just return promise. And in component you just use .then

Comment: Hi Petr Averyanov I want to do a callback once the loader has reached 100%. It is not a data call. We also do not use $q or those services. This is something I can do with an eventEmmiter, but I prefer to keep the $rootScope clean. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This is one of angular patterns -- transforming any async code into angular promise using $q service. Data call or whatever doesnt matter.

Comment: Hi @Petr Averyanov I will post my solution now. It is quite simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my service I have the following code:

**In the Service:**

```
// declare an array that will hold all my callback functions to be called after the loader has completed
private _callbacks = [];

// The method that will be called from the Controller to push the callback method into the _callbacks array
public listenLoadedComplete(callback: Function) {
    this._callbacks.push(callback);
}

// In the actual loader method set the isLoaded variable to true and call the loadingComplete method
this.isLoaderLoaded = true;
this.loadingComplete();

// The loadingCompleted method executes each registered method in the _callback array
public loadingComplete(): boolean {
    if (this.isLoaderLoaded === true) {
        for (let cb of this._callbacks) {
            cb();
        }
        return true
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**In the Controller:**

```
// Call the listenForLoadCompletion method
this.listenForLoadCompletion();

// Register the callback function in the _callback array in the Service
// After the service has completed and called the method loadingComplete, the callback will be called
public listenForLoadCompletion(): void {
    this._progressBarService.listenLoadedComplete(() => {
        this._scope.loaderHasLoaded = true;
    });
}
```